# move delimted fields into Newline with different delimted[Updated Again]

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

I have the comma seperated txt file which must have five columns only, but the some of the rows have more than 5 column.
I want to move the 6th to 10th to a newline, and 11th to 15th to a newline so on.
And 6th, 11th 16th so on column has space deleimert instead of comma

Below is the conetent of `input.txt`

```
111 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
11 2, 13, 14, 15 5, 16 11, 17, 18, 19, 20
22, 23, 24, 25, 26 22, 27, 28, 29, 21 30, 31, 32, 3333 3, 34
```

Below is the conetent of `Output.txt`

```
111 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
11 2, 13, 14, 15 5, 16
11, 17, 18, 19, 20
22, 23, 24, 25, 26
22, 27, 28, 29, 21
30, 31, 32, 3333 3, 34
```

Comment: Is it possible for there to be any spaces in the `input.txt` other than the spaces between the 5th and 6th columns, the 10th and 11th columns, etc.?

Comment: `tr ' ' '\n' < inputfile`

Comment: I can see you updated input

Comment: Your input.txt is strange: The spaces in `111 1, 11 2, 333 3` are considered as part of the data, but a space in column 5 must be considered as a field delimiter. Are you sure your fifth column can not have a space as a part of the data?

Comment: when a row has more than 5 columns, do you always have a plural of 5?
This will help for a recursive solution with IFS=, and checking the fifth field for a space.

Comment: @WalterA, Fifth column wont have space. i.e. 5th,10th,15th so on.. remaining columns may have space

Answer (score 1):

In the current (third) version of this question, it looks like we need to count four commas and then one more entity which is followed by a space (not a comma) and then add a line break at that point.  If this is the case, then use:

```
$ sed  's/\(\([^,]\+,\)\{4\}[[:space:]]\+[[:alnum:]]\+\)[[:space:]]/\1\n/g' input.txt
111 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
11 2, 13, 14, 15 5, 16
11, 17, 18, 19, 20
22, 23, 24, 25, 26
22, 27, 28, 29, 21
30, 31, 32, 3333 3, 34
```

If your `sed` supports the `-r` flag (GNU), the appearance of the command can be slightly improved:

```
sed -r 's/(([^,]+,){4}[[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]]+)[[:space:]]/\1\n/g' input.txt
```

On OSX, the `-r` flag is not supported by `-E` should work instead:

```
sed -E 's/(([^,]+,){4}[[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]]+)[[:space:]]/\1\n/g' input.txt
```

**Solution for the second version of this question**

From the examples given, we need to insert a newline every time that an column ends with a space instead of a comma.  If that is the case, then:

```
$ sed 's/\>[[:space:]]/\n/g' input.txt
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
12, 13, 14, 15, 16
11, 17, 18, 19, 20
22, 23, 24, 25, 26
22, 27, 28, 29, 21
30, 31, 32, 33, 34
```

The above works by looking for the end of a word, which `sed` denotes by `\>`, followed by whitespace of any type.  It then replaces that space with a newline.  Columns which are followed instead by a comma are left alone.

The `sed` substitute command has the form `s/old/new/` if we want to replace the first occurrence only or `s/old/new/g` if we want to replace all such occurrences.  Since we want all occurrences replaced, we use the `g`.  In the command above, the "old" part is `\>[[:space:]]` which means end-of-a-word followed by whitespace of any type.  The "new" part is just `\n` which stands for a newline.

`sed` also allows the option of changing your file in place:

```
sed -i 's/\>[[:space:]]/\n/g' input.txt
```

The `-i` option tells `sed` to change the input file in place.  After running this command, `input.txt` will be updated.

Comment: Sorry @John1024, i missed to update the input format

Comment: @GanzRicanz Thanks for clarifying.  Have a look at the revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
$ cat f1
1,2,3,4,5
12,13,14,15,16 11,17,18,19,20
22,23,24,25,26 22,27,28,29,21 30,31,32,33,34

$ awk '1' RS=' |\n' f1
1,2,3,4,5
12,13,14,15,16
11,17,18,19,20
22,23,24,25,26
22,27,28,29,21
30,31,32,33,34
```

**USER UPDATED INPUT ABOVE SOLUTION WON'T WORK**

```
$ cat f2
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
12, 13, 14, 15, 16 11, 17, 18, 19, 20
22, 23, 24, 25, 26 22, 27, 28, 29, 21 30, 31, 32, 33, 34

$ awk '{gsub(/, /,",");gsub(/ /,"\n");gsub(/,/,", ")}1'  f2

OR

$ awk '{gsub(/[[:alnum:]] /,"&\n")}1' f2

1, 2, 3, 4, 5
12, 13, 14, 15, 16
11, 17, 18, 19, 20
22, 23, 24, 25, 26
22, 27, 28, 29, 21
30, 31, 32, 33, 34
```

**Answer to below comment**

```
gsub(/, /,",")     # Substitute comma for comma + space

gsub(/ /,"\n")     # So now (field + space + field) is left, substitute space with newline  

gsub(/,/,", ")     # substitute comma space (as you requested in expected output) for comma (first argument)
```

Comment: can you please explain `awk '{gsub(/, /,",");gsub(/ /,"\n");gsub(/,/,", ")}1'`

Comment: it wont work if the column has value like `111,11 1,123,145,1`

Comment: Updated the input as well

Comment: @GanzRicanz : Yes this will not work, if your input is like that use first solution.

Answer (score 0):

I did not have time to convert the script below from ksh to bash, I leave that as a practice:

```
#!/bin/ksh
splitline() {
   echo $* | IFS=\, read f1 f2 f3 f4 f5
   # remove first space
   fx=${f5# }
   echo ${fx} | read f5a f5b
   echo "${f1},${f2},${f3},${f4}, ${f5a}"
   if [[ -n "${f5b}" ]]; then
      splitline ${f5b}
   fi
}

cat input.txt | while read line; do
   splitline $line
done
```